# Ruby: URI::InvalidURIError (URI must be ascii only

Tags: ruby

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse 'http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg'
```

The browsers have no problem with [http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg](http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/%D0%9E%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD-%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81.jpg) so I'm asking myself if this ruby class is a little bit outdated? And should I completely renounce it or do some error handling…

Comment: Just because your browser implicitly URL encodes that URL doesn't mean that Ruby would do the same. In Ruby you have to explicitly encode the URL yourself.

Comment: What you're trying to parse is not a valid URL to begin with.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The answer just came to me by asking myself the question:

```
begin
  uri = URI.parse(url)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
end
```

Comment: `uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(url))` is a better answer. `rescue` block is absolutely redundant.

Comment: @mudasobwa Careful with escaping all the things: `uri = URI.parse(URI.escape('http://example.com/not%20cool'))` yields `"http://example.com/not%2520cool"`

Comment: @tadman it depends on what `url` is built from. I’d better have `discount=5%` properly encoded :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm not sure there's an easy way to encode only non-ASCII characters, but that would be the right call here. `URI.escape` is quite limited.

Comment: @mudasobwa URI.escape is not idempotent. You want `discount=5%` properly encoded which is `discount=5%25`. What you don't want is `discount=%2525` but that's what you get when you escape it twice. This code is for dealing with "external" data which comes from unknown sources. So I have to assume that everything is correctly escaped and I possibly break it if I encode it twice.

Comment: @TNT I am not sure I follow. 1. I can not get where `%2525` could come from. 2. If you are afraid you could possible break anything encoding it twice, your code under `rescue` clause would effectively break it as well.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `URI.escape('discount=5%')` => `"discount=5%25"`; URI.escape('discount=5%25') => `"discount=5%2525"` - it was so obvious... I accidentally omitted the `5` but this can hardly have prevented you from getting the point. "URI.escape is not idempotent" says it all - doesn't it?

Comment: @TNT is completely correct with it **not being idempotent**. I think this illustrates it a little better, though: `URI.escape( URI.escape('discount=5%') ) #=> "discount=5%2525"`

Comment: `URI.escape` is no longer available in Ruby as of 3.0. The ruby-lang docs suggest to use `URI.encode_www_form` or `CGI.escape`, neither of which will help you parse a URI with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 19):

With kudus to all the `URI.escape` answers (also known as `URI.encode`), these methods have been officially **made obsolete** by Ruby 2.7 - i.e. they now produce a visible `URI.escape is obsolete` warning message when you use them - previously they have just been deprecated. In Ruby 3.0 these methods have been **completely removed** and are no longer available at all - not even with a warning.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the Ruby's standard library `URI` class does not offer any alternative for handling URIs containing non-ASCII characters, which are all so common these days - <sarcasm>*now that the web had gone international*</sarcasm>.

The best solution I came up with is using the [addressable](https://rubygems.org/gems/addressable/) gem that contains the `URI` class we deserve - it handles everything the world has to throw at it and you can get an "HTTP safe" URI using the `#display_uri` method:

```rb
Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg")
=> #<Addressable::URI:0xc8 URI:http://example.com/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg>
```

```rb
Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg").display_uri.to_s
=> "http://example.com/%D0%9E%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD-%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81.jpg"
```

`Addressable::URI` also comes with all kinds of goodies, such as port inferral (you can tell whether the URL originally contained a port specification, or you can not care), and URL canonicalization (given a base URL, take a possibly relative URL and generate an absolute URL).

Here's how to use this with `net/http`:

```rb
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.inferred_port, 
        :use_ssl => url.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.display_uri.request_uri)
end
```

Comment: There is a solution not using `Addressable` but pure `uri` module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849219/ruby-uriinvalidurierror-uri-must-be-ascii-only/75487328#answer-75487328

Answer (score 12):

## TL;DR

### Ruby < 3.0 (not recommended)

```rb
uri = URI.parse(URI.escape(url))
```

### Ruby > 2.0 (recommended)

```rb
uri = URI.parse(URI::Parser.new.escape(url))
```

## Explanation

`URI.escape` / `URI.encode` has been removed since Ruby 3.0. This solution offers to use pure Ruby `uri` module rather than relaying on an third-party gem.

Comment: You are of course right that Ruby 2.x is a bit outdated. But you completely missed the point that the escape function isn't idempotent. Your code doesn't work with already escaped urls. Just mentioning.

Answer (score 9):

What do you think about:

```rb
url = URI.escape(url) unless url.ascii_only?
URI.parse(url)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can map the URL characters and escape the ones that are not ASCII. Something like this:

```
url.chars.map { |char| char.ascii_only? ? char : CGI.escape(char) }.join
```

Comment: quick and easy fix without installing another gem. Thanks!

Comment: Similar to: `uri = iri.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]/) { CGI.escape _1 }`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error:

> Ruby: URI::InvalidURIError (URI must be ascii only

with my code, but my bug was that it was an old project and the i18n was outdated. It was solved, with a simple:

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score -1):

```
URI.encode('your-url')
```

This worked for me

Comment: This works well up until Ruby 2.7, after which you get a warning and in Ruby 3.0 it no longer works at all.

Answer (score -1):

https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2023/02/14/escaping-encoding-uri-components-in-ruby-3-2/

TLDR;

Ruby 3.2

```rb
require 'cgi'
 
url = "https://example.com/some/#{ CGI.escapeURIComponent path_component }" + 
  "?#{CGI.escapeURIComponent my_key}=#{CGI.escapeURIComponent my_value}"
```

< Ruby 3.2

```rb
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape(input).gsub("+", "%20")
```

or

```rb
require 'erb'
ERB::Util.url_encode(input)
```

Comment: This answer is about how to encode non-ASCII components into a URI string. The quest was about how to parse string URIs with such components into an URI object.