# Simple alternative to URI.escape

Tags: ruby, escaping, uri

While using `URI.parse` on a URL, I was confronted with an error message:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only
```

I found [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849219/ruby-uriinvalidurierror-uri-must-be-ascii-only) that recommended using `URI.escape`, which works. Using the URL in that question as an example:

```
URI.parse('http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg')
=> URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only "http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/\u041E\u0443\u044D\u043D-\u041C\u044D\u0442\u044C\u044E\u0441.jpg"

URI.encode('http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg')
=> "http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/%D0%9E%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD-%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81.jpg"
```

However, `URI.escape` is obsolete, as [Rubocop](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) warns:

```
URI.escape method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use CGI.escape, URI.encode_www_form or URI.encode_www_form_component depending on your specific use case.
```

But while `URI.escape` gives us a usable result, the alternatives don’t:

```
CGI.escape('http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg')
=> "http%3A%2F%2Fdxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F10%2F%D0%9E%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD-%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%81.jpg"
```

This is a bother because in my case I’m constructing a URL from data I get via [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/):

```
my_url = page.at('.someclass').at('img').attr('src')
```

Since I only need to escape the last part of the resulting URL, but `CGI.escape` and similar transform the whole string (including necessary characters, such as `:` and `/`), getting the escaped result now becomes a multiple-lines-of-code ordeal, having to split the path and using several variables to achieve what could be previously done with a single function (`URI.escape`).

Is there a simple alternative I’m not seeing? It needs to be done without external gems.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use [`Addressable`](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) for parsing URLs since the standard `URI` has flaws:

```
require 'addressable'

Addressable::URI.parse('http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg')
#<Addressable::URI:0x3fc37ecc1c40 URI:http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg> 

Addressable::URI.parse('http://dxczjjuegupb.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg').path
# "/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Оуэн-Мэтьюс.jpg"
```

It isn't part of the Ruby core or the standard library but it should be and it always ends up in my `Gemfile`s.

Comment: “It isn't part of the Ruby core or the standard library but it should be”. Unfortunately that makes it unsuitable (forgot to add that to the question). In the environments I need it to work, external gems are a no-go.